# ¿Cómo comparar date en jpql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo un proyecto web con Java 8, Apache Tomcat y Postgresql 9.3 y necesito comparar los dates, este es el código delo controlador:

```
public Curso findCursoByFechaInicio(Date inicio) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            Curso p = (Curso) em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Curso c WHERE c.iniciocurso=" + inicio).getSingleResult();
            return p;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

El `iniciocurso` es de tipo `Date` de java.Util.Date y cuando le paso el `Date` de inicio con los mismos valores de uno que existe en la base de datos (lo compruebo durante el debbug) lanza una excepcion en la consulta.

Comment: que tipo de excepcion? cual es el error que da? es muy probable que sea por el formato de la fecha

Comment: la excepcion la da el método que lo invoca, que es el de editar, este codigo devuelve null porque no encuentra el curso con esa fecha de inicio y el otro al tratar de editar el curso da NullPointerException. Los valores son los mismos, lo combrobe en el debugg, ademas de que los datos los cargo de una tabla que fue llenada con los datos de la base de datos, es decir que si existen. No se que mas hacer.

Comment: El formato de la fecha es muy probable que este mal.

Comment: disculpa la insistencia pero es que tomo la fecha de un <b:datepicker> de bootsfaces y en los dos casos y me devuelve directamente un java.Util.Date y eso es lo que le paso al metodo, por eso no veo como puede haber diferencia entre uno y otro en cuanto al formato.

Comment: Las bases de datos manejan las fechas en formatos particulares de ellas. Proba la query tal como decis q viene la fecha a ver si devuelve algo. Una cosa es el manejo de fechas de java y otra las db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La query que estas creando es un String normal al que encadenas el "toString" del objeto Date "inicio". Probablemente el resultado del "toString" de este objeto Date no coincida con el formato de la fecha en la BBDD.

Lo mejor para evitar estos casos es dejar la transformación del objeto date al formato de la base de datos al ORM que estés usando.

Puedes probar a construir la query con un parámetro dinámico e informarlo a después.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Curso WHERE c.iniciocurso= :fechaInicio");
query.setParameter("fechaInicio", fechaInicio);
Curso p = query.getSingleResult();
```

Al poner ":nombreVariable" el entity manager sabe que es un parámetro que tendrá que manejar.